# finding the pivotal quantity

Tags: statistics

$f(x|\theta)= \frac{2(\theta -x)}{\theta^2}$

I'm looking to find the pivotal quantity of this probability density. I'm not really sure how to proceed because I have only seen examples of this done with normal distributions.

If I consider $Y=\frac{\theta -x}{\theta}$, then this would make more sense. I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: That is a pdf for $0<x<\theta$, so $X/\theta$ is a pivot as its distribution does not depend on $\theta$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Since $Y=1-\frac{X}{\theta}$, if one is a pivotal quantity then so too is the other, though $\frac{X}{\theta}$ may be easier to work with as it has the same distribution as $X$ when $\theta=1$